# Scala: List to List of Lists, idiomatically?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala, I wrote a Higher Order Function that iterates a list, and calls back with the head and list, for each element, that is:

```
  def headAndSelf[A, B](li: List[A], f: (A, List[A]) => B): List[B] = { 
    if (li == Nil) Nil
    else f(li.head, li) :: headAndSelf(li.tail, f)
  }
```

Given `val a = List(1,2,3)`

```
scala> headAndSelf(a, (x: Int, y: List[Int]) => (x,y))
res4: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((1,List(1, 2, 3)), (2,List(2, 3)), (3,List(3)))
```

It then occurred to me I could get the head from the list, so it was simpler to write:

```
  def self[A, B](li: List[A], f: (List[A]) => B): List[B] = { 
    if (li == Nil) Nil
    else f(li) :: self(li.tail, f)
  }
```

(even though it makes the lambda a bit less elegant)

```
scala> self(a, (x: List[Int]) => x)
res7: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3), List(3))
```

Then I thought, surely there's an even easier, idiomatic way to turn a List into a List of Lists. So what is it?

Bonus Question: why can't Scala infer the type of the lambda? `a` is a `List[Int]`, so `x` should be a `List[Int]` too, no?:

```
scala> self(a, x => x)
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type
       self(a, x => x)
               ^
```

Comment: the if(li == Nil) is not idomatic. Use pattern matching here : `li match { case Nil => Nil; case head :: tail => f(head, tail)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tails` will do most of the job.

`tails` will have an empty list as its last element, and you need to filter that out, which is what `collect` does below:

```
def headAndSelf[A,B](l: List[A])(f: (A, List[A]) => B) = 
  l.tails.collect{case list @ head :: _ => f(head, list)}.toList
```

Having two parameters lists as demonstrated here will allow proper type inference. You need two list at call site too, but it is often convenient :

```
headAndSelf(yourList){(h,l) => whatever}
```